# Angular 5 transfer state api

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-universal

I am trying to use transfer state api to hold the values of my api calls so that I can avoid duplicate requests.

I currently have for my code:

```
const STATE_KEY_RESPONSES = makeStateKey(url);
if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId) && this.state.hasKey(STATE_KEY_RESPONSES)) {
  return new Promise(() => this.state.get(STATE_KEY_RESPONSES, null));
} else {
  return this.model.hcGet(url, options)
    .toPromise()
    .then((response) => {
      if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
        this.state.set(STATE_KEY_RESPONSES, response);
      }
      return response;
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

However it appears (whenever I call `console.log(this.state)`) that the object doesn't get stored to the state for retrieval(this.state.get)
I noticed that if I take this.state.set out of isPlatformServer(this.platformId) it stores my key in the state

..
Things I have tried/already implemented(everything):

```
*ServerTransferStateModule,
*ModuleMapLoaderModule,
*BrowserTransferStateModule,
*TransferHttpCacheModule,
*    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({
  appId: "my-app-id",
}),
*providers: [{
provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
useClass: UniversalInterceptor,
/* Multi is important or you will delete all the other interceptors */
multi: true,
}],
```

I dont know what else to do, the requests also happen on the client side not the server side